# Xcode 3.2. Debugging a shared library doesn't work

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, osx-snow-leopard, shared-libraries

Xcode 3.2.6, 10.6.8, C++ Project, with a bit of Objective-C.

I have a project that uses a shared library (that I have all the code for and can build whenever). I am crashing someplace when I reach the shared library and I cannot figure out why. I have all the .h files that make up the shared library in my project and I link to the .a. I build and link without errors.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I have built the shared library with Debug symbols
2. I have placed a break-point in the shared library .cpp file where I should enter but Xcode does not stop at it.
3. I have tried placing `NSLog` statements in the shared library and building it again to see if they show up in the console and I dont see where they do before the crash.

How does one debug an app that crashes in a shared library. I seem to recall I could do this in Metrowerks years ago.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you might not actually be using the shared library that you built: make sure your application isn't picking up a version installed in a system location, or something like that: you can use `otool -L` to list the libraries that a binary links against to make absolutely certain.